# Reflected in zero, or Reflected at zero

Tags: stochastic-processes

When considering a stochastic process such as a geometric Brownian motion. Is it correct to say that it is reflected **in** zero? Or would it be reflected **at** zero?

Purely interested in what the correct wording is.

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever seen it written or said as "reflected **at** zero."  However, it's worth pointing out that a geometric Brownian motion has $0$ probability of hitting zero in finite time, so it's a bit of a moot point in that particular example.

Comment: There's also reflected _through_ $0$...